# Get Code of 'Export To Excel' Button of SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, button, powerapps-forms

The guys who works on SharePoint list's knows that there is a button to extract all the data in Excel file. Like below.
[image: Reference Snap]

I am building an Application in PowerApps, where i am thinking to add a button as 'Extract Data'. On click i want the same action to be executed similar i click on 'Export to Excel' button.

Can anyone please help how to do that?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can add a flow to your application in PowerApps to export data to a csv file which can be used in Excel.

Here is a video providing a step-to-step tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imhxy3REgXc

Comment: Hi @Jerry_MSFT, Thanks for responding. I gone through the video of Shane but it is for more complex requirement where i can select the specific records and then i can export them using Flow. However my requirement is bit simple. I was the entire list to be extracted when i click on the button embedded in the PowerApp. Can you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: @AkshayMankeAk You can have a check on this:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-do-I-export-the-Contents-of-a-Data-Table-to-Excel/td-p/135779 And as I am not an expert on PowerApps, you can post a new thread there.